# What am I doing wrong parsing HTML with Goquery using a class selector?

Tags: jquery, go, goquery

I'm using [goquery](https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Find) to get some data from some sites. I have no problem when the element has an `id`, but it seems I can't make it work when the element only has a `class`.

For example, assume this [site](https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/86444331/). I want to retrieve the name and the price. To do so, I'm using:

```
func fetch(doc *goquery.Document) (name string, price string) {
    name = doc.Find(".main-info__title-main").Text()
    if name == "" {
        log.Fatal("Could not retrieve property name")
    }
    price = doc.Find(".info-data-price").Text()
    if price == "" {
        log.Fatal("Could not retrieve property price")
    }
    return name, price
}
```

However, I'm both cases the content is always `""`. If instead of `class`, the `span` had an `id`, it would works without any issues, changing `.` for `#`, i.e. `doc.Find("#main-info__title-main").Text()`. So, what am I doing wrong here, using the selector by `class` name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the code was actually ok. Further debugging I found that the site wasn't correctly fetched due to CAPTCHA.